# Which dependencies do I need to add when publishing a vue component to npm?

Tags: vue.js, npm, vue-cli-3, npm-publish

I have built a vue component that I want to publish to npm (already did so), but I was wondering if I need to add vue as dependency and if that will affect the size of the component. Currently my package.json looks like this

```
"dependencies": {
    "vue": "^2.6.6",
    "vue-svg-loader": "^0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-eslint": "^3.0.5",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^3.0.5",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "eslint": "^5.8.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^5.0.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.5.21"
  },
```

I'm using the vue-cli-service to build my component with the following command

```
vue-cli-service build --target lib --name my_component_name ./src/index.js
```

I had the feeling that for the fairly small component I am building, the bundle size is relativly big

This is my output:

File | Size | Gzipped

dist\my_component.umd.min.js | 61.67 KiB | 18.62 KiB

dist\my_component.umd.js | 143.66 KiB | 32.61 KiB

dist\my_component.common.js | 143.27 KiB | 32.49 KiB

So - long story short: I was wondering if the dependency on vue will increase my bundle size and if it is actually required as dependency when publishing a single component.

Comment: [Your answer is in the docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/build-targets.html#app). If you want to short version it's, "Vue is not bundled"

Comment: vue should be under `peerDependencies`.